# How to use Marketplace Extension in Magento 2?

Tags: extensions, magento2.3

I have a task regarding seller registration. We have installed Marketplace extension in Magento 2 but I don't have any idea how to use this extension.

Could anyone please help with this?

Regards,

Comment: You can follow the user guide if extension vendor provided the same

Comment: @nishu, I have checked and see that they have provided user guide but it's hard to understand.

Comment: Which extension are you using. can you send me the link. Hope i can help

Comment: https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-marketplace-extension.html

Comment: did you check their live demo and if still it doesn't help you then you can ask from the support team for a setup demo. This will help you alot...